# How to get rid of req.params.id in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js

I created controller in 'api/controllers/UserController.js' and created an action there:

```
hello: function(req, res){
    console.log('PARAMS:', req.params);
    return res.send('hello');
}
```

When I hit in address line "http://localhost:1337/user/hello/erer" console.log() says:

```
PARAMS: [ id: 'erer' ]
```

But I need 404.

In config/blueprint.js I changed several lines:

```
rest: false,
shortcuts: false,
```

Comment: Please show your routes, full object of `blueprints.js` and `_config` if you have it in your controller

Comment: You probably created route user/hello/:id . So whatever you type after hello/ will be id route param... You can name your route param as you wish for example: user/hello/:username

Comment: I just created new project typing: "sails new test". I don't need any params after "host/controller/action" by default. I only changed "rest" and "shortcuts" in config.js file. In route.js only these lines:

    '/': {
        view: 'homepage'
    }

Comment: To troubleshoot you may want to change your log level to "silly" (config/log.js) to see what routes are being registered. I wouldn't think any of the shadow routes would match the url you listed, but I typically turn off action routes.

Answer (score 0):

As the [documentation](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/blueprint-api#?disabling-blueprints-on-a-percontroller-basis) explains, in order to disable the blueprints onto a single controller you have to override the blueprints configuration inside your controller by exporting an object `_config`